# Solving a system of linear equations in Clifford Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I’m interested in solving the following system of equations in $\mathbb{Cl}(2,0)$:

$$\boldsymbol{Z}_{11}\boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{Z}_{12}\boldsymbol{x}_2+\ldots+\boldsymbol{Z}_{1n}\boldsymbol{x}_n=\boldsymbol{a}_1$$

$$\boldsymbol{Z}_{21}\boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{Z}_{22}\boldsymbol{x}_2+\ldots+\boldsymbol{Z}_{2n}\boldsymbol{x}_n=\boldsymbol{a}_2$$

$$\boldsymbol{Z}_{m1}\boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{Z}_{m2}\boldsymbol{x}_2+\ldots+\boldsymbol{Z}_{mn}\boldsymbol{x}_n=\boldsymbol{a}_m$$

where $\boldsymbol{Z}_{ij}$ are bivectors and $\boldsymbol{a}_i$ are vectors. The unknowns are $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ which are also vectors.

M. E. Horn used exterior algebra to solve a similar system where all the coefficients are scalars [here](http://www.phydid.de/index.php/phydid-b/article/viewFile/626/795) (page 12).

**Edited**: How to solve if $\boldsymbol{Z}_{ij}$ are spinors? Then, multiplying both sides by $\boldsymbol{e}_{12}$ seems to be not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is Cl(2,0), every bivector is a scalar multiple of the unit pseudoscalar (i = e_1 e_2).  Multiply both sides by i, and you are left with a set of vector equations, which you can solve using any method you desire.

For the special case of spinor $ Z_{ij} \in \mathbb{Cl}(2,0) $ (assuming spinor here means multivectors with only even grades),
we can setup this system of equations in matrix form, provided we are careful with the ordering of products.  For example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}   Z_{11} & Z_{12} \\    Z_{21} & Z_{22} \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 \\    x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}   a_1 \\    a_2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Here we must define matrix multiplication so that any products are taken in the order of the matrices.  That is
$$\begin{bmatrix}   Z_{11} & Z_{12} \\    Z_{21} & Z_{22} \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 \\    x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}   Z_{11} x_1 + Z_{12} x_2  \\    Z_{21} x_1 + Z_{22} x_2\end{bmatrix},$$
and not
$$\begin{bmatrix}   Z_{11} & Z_{12} \\    Z_{21} & Z_{22} \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 \\    x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 Z_{11} + Z_{12} x_2  \\    Z_{21} x_1 + x_2 Z_{22}\end{bmatrix},$$
or any other permutation.  Because the even grade elements of $ Z_{ij} \in \mathbb{Cl}(2,0) $ all commute (this space is isomorphic to complex numbers),
we can just invert this leading matrix.
$$\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 \\    x_2\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{{ Z_{11} Z_{22} - Z_{12} Z_{21} }}\begin{bmatrix}   Z_{22} & -Z_{12} \\   -Z_{21} & Z_{11} \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}   a_1 \\    a_2\end{bmatrix}.$$
We still must be careful with ordering when the $ 2x2 $ matrix inverse is multiplied with the matrix of vectors, but multiplying that out should solve the system.

This approach should also be possible for similar systems in this space with more variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peeter. I edited the question to elaborate more on this. What if $Z_{ij}$ are spinors?

Comment: By spinors in this context, I assume that you mean scalar + bivector elements?  Interesting question.  You could generalize to general multivector elements.  I don't know the answer, but will play around with it.

Comment: Yes, spinors as scalar+bivector. Finally, you ended up using a matrix form as I suspected. As you mentioned, spinors are isomorphic to complex numbers, so this solution is already known.
This system of equations appears in power systems and circuit theory when using phasors (frequency domain).

So the solution is a mix of GA and matrix algebra